# gmapping bag rviz problem

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am following the [gmapping tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData)

But rviz can not draw the map out:

I've add the MAP display,but with the error "No transform from [] to [map]".

No map disappear but a black square in the view.

Did I miss some key configurations?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227427/gmapping-bag-rviz-problem/) by [SHI.ZP](https://answers.ros.org/users/25720/shi.zp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2016-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Choose `/map` in the Global options -> Fixed Frame menu.
2. Choose `/map` in the Map -> Topic menu.

---

Originally posted by [yasagitov](https://answers.ros.org/users/23174/yasagitov/) with karma: 223 on 2016-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SHI.ZP](https://answers.ros.org/users/25720/shi.zp/) on 2016-02-24**:
It works, Thank you!